# How do I add a variable’s value to an array?

Tags: arrays, perl, file, text

I am looking for files in a directory. If I can’t find the file, I want to send the name of that file to an array, so that by the time the loop is done I’ll have an array of the files that weren’t found. How do I code this in Perl?

```
foreach $missing (@miss) {
    chomp $missing;
    ($a,$b)=split(/\.m_inproc./,$missing);

    @find = `find /home1/users/virtual/ -name .m_inproc.$b`;
    $find_size = scalar @find;
    $flag = "/home1/t01jkxj/check_st/flags/$b";

    if ($find_size < 1 && -e $flag) {
        $doit = `$b > @re_missing`;
    }
}
```

This is my searching code, and if it doesn’t find a file (`$find_size` is less than 1) and there is a flag file (meaning we’ve done this search before). I want to write that variable `$b` (the filename) to an array. Obviously, my syntax currently `($doit = $b > @re_missing;)` is incorrect. What would it be? Thanks!

Comment: What is in `@missing`? Are elements of `@missing` full paths to files? Do you expect that the files have been moved? Or, are the full paths not correct?

Answer (score 1):

How about:

```
push @re_missing, $b
```

By the way, using $a and $b are bad form.  These are the implicitly declared variables used in the body of the comparator for [`sort`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/sort.html).

Answer (score 0):

Not sure of the full context of your code but this code - combined with your already implemented file size checking - should put you on the right track. The short answer here is "USE PUSH" but I felt like coding things, so sorry for that if that causes unneccesary reading and "use push" would have sufficed.

```
#usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;

my @files = ("tester.txt", "pooter.txt", "output.txt"); 
my @notfound;


foreach(@files)
{
    if (!(-e $_))
    {
        push (@notfound, $_);
    }
}

foreach(@notfound)
{
    print $_;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
my @missing_files = grep { ! -e } @files_to_search_for;
```

Comment: Except that I think `find` searches under subdirectories as well. This is crying out for a simple `File::Find` based solution.